# Laravel not creating log file.

Tags: php, logging, laravel-4, monolog

I'm learning Laravel 4.0 to develop a webserver.
I'm using a LAMP stack (Apache 2, php 5.5).
I can't find the log file where Log::error() calls writes to.
As far as I know it's supposed to be to app/storage/logs/log-cli-.txt but there are no files there.

Here is the code:

```
app/commands/MsgCommand.php
public function fire(){
   Log::error('messages - log');
}
```

It's called from artisan:

```
app/start/artisan.php
Artisan::add(new MsgCommand());
```

Am I looking in the right place?
How can I check that this is indeed the right folder (i.e. where is it configured)? To check for faulty installation or setup.

Thanks to marcanuy, I am now sure it is writing to app/storage/logs.
Also I found out it writes fine if I call the command through artisan. Running on apache 2 nothing happens though. I'm starting to think I set up the command wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was permissions.
User permissions for the www-var user in the ../app/storage
And MySQL settings: Creating a user corresponding to what is set in the app/config/database.php

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'your host',
            'database'  => 'your db',
            'username'  => 'your user',
            'password'  => 'your pass',
           ),
```

Answer (score 8):

By default app/storage is the location for log files, storage folder is configured in [bootstrap/paths.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/paths.php#L55)

```
    'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',
```

Also be sure that this folder is writable by the web server.

Comment: Thanks, I see it and it has the default path. I have writing permission.